# Keras functional API and TensorFlow Hub

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use a [Universal Sentence Encoder](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual-large/1) from TF Hub as a keras layer in a functional way. I would like to use `hub.KerasLayer` with Keras Functional API, but i'm not sure how to achieve that, so far I've only seen exmaples of hub.KerasLayer with the Sequential API

```py
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tf_sentencepiece


use_url = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual-large/1'

english_sentences = ["dog", "Puppies are nice.", "I enjoy taking long walks along the beach with my dog."]
english_sentences = np.array(english_sentences, dtype=object)[:, np.newaxis]


seq = layers.Input(shape=(None, ), name='sentence', dtype=tf.string)
module = hub.KerasLayer(hub.Module(use_url))(seq)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[seq], outputs=[module])
model.summary()

x = model.predict(english_sentences)
print(x)
```

the code above runs into this error when passing the input layer to the embedding: `TypeError: Can't convert 'inputs': Shape TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None)]) is incompatible with TensorShape([Dimension(None)])`

Is it possible to use hub.KerasLayer with keras functional API in TensorFlow 1.x? if it can be done, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
sentence_encoding_layer = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4",
                                         trainable=False,
                                         input_shape = [],
                                         dtype = tf.string,
                                         name = 'U.S.E')

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (), dtype = 'string',name = 'input_layer')

x = sentence_encoding_layer(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64,activation = 'relu')(x)

outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation = 'sigmoid',name = 'output_layer')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs,outputs,name = 'Transfer_learning_USE')
model.summary()
```

model.predict([sentence])

Answer (score 1):

If you use [v3](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual-large/3) of the same universal sentence encoder with tf 1.15, you can do such thing by replacing lines from

```py
import tf_sentencepiece
use_url = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual-large/1'
module = hub.KerasLayer(hub.Module(use_url))(seq)
```

to

```py
import tensorflow_text
use_url = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual-large/3'
module = hub.KerasLayer(use_url)(seq)
```

Answer (score 0):

First shape is what you are passing into the model, `Shape TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None)])`. Second shape is what you are expecting, `TensorShape([Dimension(None)])`. So in this error, its telling you it expecting a shape of ()...

Or

If you are expecting to do batches of text, perhaps do [TimeDistributed](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TimeDistributed#class_timedistributed) layer, like so...

```
module = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(hub.KerasLayer(hub.Module(use_url)))(seq)
```

However you maybe forced to do specific size for text length...